# Adding meta tag programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to programmatically add a `<meta>`. It is working fine when there is a `Head` element with `runat = "server"` in the `.aspx` page.

The code behind is:

```
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
meta.Name = "robots";
meta.Content = "noindex,follow";
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```

But I have some script in the head tag which contains code blocks like `<% ... %>`, so I cannot keep the `runat = "server"` value.

The problem is I have to add the meta tag programmatically, because it depends on a value from the database.

Is there a way to solve this issue so that my script inside the head element works as usual and I can add a meta tag programmatically?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

OK, I tested the [answer by **veggerby**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432431/adding-meta-tag-programatically-in-c/1432450#1432450), and it works perfectly:

In the `<header>` section:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="MetaPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
```

Note that Visual Studio might show a warning on the PlaceHolder tag, because it is not recognised as a known element inside the header, but you can ignore this. It works.

In the C# code:

```
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
meta.Name = "robots";
meta.Content = "noindex,follow";
MetaPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(meta);
```

Alternatively (since you already have code blocks using `<% %>` in your header section), you can tag the meta directly and retrieve only the value from server side:

```
<meta name="robots" content="<%=GetMetaRobotsValueFromDatabase()%>" />
```

Comment: Apologies - The code was too long to post as a comment so I added an answer (using your code) below.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Many thanks to [Awe for the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432431/adding-meta-tag-programmatically-in-c-sharp/1432532#1432532)! I have implemented this code in a (error404.ascx) ASP.NET User Control as follows:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"%>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;  //Suppress IIS7 custom errors
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        SetRobotsHeaderMetadata();
    }

    private void SetRobotsHeaderMetadata()
    {
        HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
        meta.Name = "robots";
        meta.Content = "noindex,follow";
        this.Page.Master.FindControl("cphPageMetaData").Controls.Add(meta);
    }
</script>
```

With the following masterpage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MyMaster" %>
<script runat="server">
    ...
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <title>Site title here</title>

        <asp:contentplaceholder runat="server" id="cphPageMetaData">
        </asp:contentplaceholder>
    </head>

    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Or you could just put your meta-tag in the header, with an ID and a runat="server"... then in the code behind say

```
myMetaTag.Content = "noindex,follow";
```

or

```
myMetaTag.Visible = false;
```

or whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is the best approach:

```
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<meta ... />"));
```

Enjoy!

Comment: I know it is a bit late but is there any reason you chose to use a `LiteralControl` over an [`HtmlMeta`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlmeta?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Additionally I dont think this answers the OPs question since the Header is not a server control. Page.Header will be null

Answer (score 5):

Try moving whatever it is that you are doing in the <% .... %> to the code-behind. If you are using the script to add content into the page, you can replace it with an asp:Literal control and then set the value you were previously calculating in the script block to the code-behind and set Literal.Text to that value.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it, but maybe you can add an `<asp:Placeholder>` inside the `<head></head>` tag and add the meta tags to this.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this, which I successfully checked without any error or warning:

The JavaScript code, which contains the `<% ... %>` code, was removed from the `head` section and placed in the `body` section.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your meta tag as a static string like so:

```
Private Shared MetaLanguage As String =
    String.Format("<meta http-equiv=""Content-Language"" content=""{0}""/>", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)
```

Then place them in your head like so:

```
<head runat="server">
    <%=MetaLanguage%>
</head>
```

This allow you to use any meta tag values and is easy to read and customize. Note: The use of the `Shared` keyword (static) helps improve performance.

Answer (score -3):

MetaDescription = "Your meta description goes here";
  MetaKeywords = "Keyword1,Keyword2,Keyword3";

Answer (score -3):

OK... I actually only use C#... Or HTML into C#. *I never use codebehind, designer or webcontrols in the file aspx...* So I program *everything* from classes... And dynamically.

Result:

```
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
meta.Name = "robots";
`meta.Content = "Here is what you want";`
var page=HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```