# Metatag displays as html ouptout (aspx page)

Tags: asp.net, html, meta-tags

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);
    Literal lTags = new Literal();
    lTags.Text = "<meta name=\"MetaTagsDemo\" content=\"Meta demo tag\" />";
    this.Header.Controls.Add(lTags);
}
```

I have the the above code in my default.aspx.cs. When Default.aspx page is loaded I do see the control getting added within section but on top of the page (very 1st line in the page), the html display is "".

What am I doing wrong here?

I have another page named Browse.aspx where I have the same feature but this page doesn't show the html output.

**UPDATE**

Source for meta tags is database and whole metatag is stored in one field

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Meta Tag Programatically in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432431/adding-meta-tag-programatically-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add meta tag as a html control, something like this :

```
HtmlMeta tag = new HtmlMeta();
tag.Name = "MetaTagsDemo";
tag.Content = "Meta demo tag";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(tag);
```

UPDATE:

Yes, you should parse database input, with HtmlAgilityPack this is a easy task, for example :

```
  HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
  doc.LoadHtml("<meta name=\"MetaTagsDemo\" content=\"Meta demo tag\" />");
  foreach (HtmlNode meta in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta"))
  {
    string metaName = meta.Attributes["Name"].Value;
    string content = meta.Attributes["Content"].Value;
    /// do something
  }
```

UPDATE 2

No HtmlAgilityPack, here is a quick and dirty method, you should test it

```
  string meta = "<meta name=\"MetaTagsDemo\" content=\"Meta demo tag\" />";
  string[] splitted = meta.Split('"');
  string metaName = splitted[1];
  string metaContent = splitted[3];
```

Comment: I am actually reading the value from database and the value contains both 'name' and 'content'. Should I parse the string and assign values? Any other options or suggestions?

Comment: I am not allowed to download or use htmlagilitypack. I tried with system.windows.forms namespace but it has constructor errors (also mine is asp.net website). Please suggest or any other options. thanks.

Comment: I just printed the actual string coming from database. Looks strange but here is the value. I am trying to parse it now.                 <div class="ExternalClassA3cA"><p>&lt;meta name=&quot;MetaTagsDemo&quot;content=&quot;Meta demo tag&quot;/&gt;<br/></p></div>

Comment: Another update. Found while checking values that the actual string coming from database has multiple MetaName & Content.

Comment: @Anirudh well something you have to do your self :) These strange string are encoded characters use html decode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx