# How to add meta tag within master page?How to add description dynamically in meta tag?

Tags: asp.net, meta-tags

I have a page say news.aspx where I am displaying News. I have a separate master page say master_news.master which I am calling with in news.aspx. I want to use meta tag within this master page. But the problem is with in  within content I want to fetch brief news data which I am storing in database and display within content part of the meta tag.
I have tried doing this-
aspx page-

```
<meta name="description" content="<%=brief %>" />
```

.cs page-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            news();
        }
    }

public void news()
    {
        dt = g1.return_dt("select substring(brief,0,300) as brief1 from tbl1 where xid=" + Request.QueryString["id"]);
        brief = dt.Rows[0]["brief1"].ToString();
    }
```

Please guide me whether I am doing right or I am doing something wrong?If not please suggest some other alternatives. Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432431/adding-meta-tag-programatically-in-c-sharp

Comment: @abhitalks: I can directly use news() function within the content part of the meta tag???
like this-
<meta name="description" content="<%=news() %>" />

Answer (score 1):

Master page has no access to Content page Properties.

You could define a property Brief in MasterPage, and then set this property from the content page doing:

```
((MasterType)this.Master).Brief = this.brief;
```